# Blender 2.8 Having trouble with scaling

Tags: scale

I'm wondering why my object shrinks a little after I scale it, I mean it does make the shape bigger but not as much as I scale it to be. When I click off of it the object shrinks down a little. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: No i think so because i've deleted the object muliple times to redo it bc i watching a tutorial and messed up a little so it keeps doing the same thing and also another question the guy i'm watching when he is in wireframe mode his object is there while mine is hollow just the out line of it is there would you know why

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a constraint applied to the object - eg constrain the scale to no bigger than a value?

For the hollow wireframe part - you may be wanting to toggle x-ray mode Alt-Z or the button next to the wireframe shading.